# Как ограничить сайт только моб версией?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть обычный сайт с десктоп и моб версией. Как сделать так чтобы работала только моб версия? Файл стилей единый и моб версия прописана при помощи @media.

Нужно чтоб сайт расширялся не более 375 пикселей и при этом работали @media

Если ограничить ширину сайта стилями, то ширина браузера все равно большая и @media не работает.

Не переписывать же весь ксс под моб версию??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы срабатывали стили из медиазапроса при ширине экрана максимум 375 пикселей на большей ширине экрана, просто укажите большую ширину экрана в медиазапросе.
Например вместо

```
@media (max-width: 375px)
```

сделайте

```
@media (max-width: 1980px)
```